# Outdoor bayonet light fixture stopped working

Tags: light, bulb, lamp

I cannot for the life of me figure this out, it isn't important enough to call an electrician out and it doesn't warrant the expensive cost but I'd really like to get it working.

During house viewings, the outdoor front porch light (protected from rain & wind) housed a 100W B22 bulb that functioned fine. It must have blown out a bit before we moved in. I've tried two new 8W B22 bulbs on it and it simply wont turn on. The light switch panel and wiring behind it seems relatively new and all wired up correctly. The socket itself seems clean and nothing is broken.

Could anybody help out? Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified that there is actually voltage? Is there a motion sensor the lower wattage lamp might have issues with motion sensors or electronic switches, and last I know it is new but have you tried another lamp.

Comment: I've just checked with a voltage tester and there's no beep or light, nothing running through it. No motion sensors nearby. Don't know what to do now

Comment: Is the light simply switched or on a timer or some sort of automatic control?

Comment: It's switched on with an ordinary household switch, located inside, right by the door. There are two switches on the same panel, one which operates an indoor corridor switch and works just fine, and the other is the problematic outdoor light. None of the bulbs or switches in my house are dimmers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no measured voltage , I would be looking for a fuse or circuit breaker that has tripped. That bulb style in not used in my area for mains lighting. In my area I would work back to the switch then to find what feeds the switch sometimes a receptacle looking for another dead device that could have caused the open circuit or no voltage continuing to work back to the main power panel verifying that any branch fuses are good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the garage recently. Turned out to be one of the spring-loaded prongs in the fitting wasn't touching the bulb. It hadn't had a change of bulb in months, and worked up till that occasion. Odd. Pressed it a few times,(with power off!) and all was o.k.

Comment: I see, I've just had a look and the prongs seem to be touching the bulb fine unfortunately